# MacOs Excel 2011 VBA Macro Add a Comma and Space after String Pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a string pattern of varying length and add a comma and space after that string pattern.  For example, Search for the string "Cat. 123" I want to replace that string with the value "Cat. 123, " (i.e. add a comma and then a space at the end of "Cat. 123").  I am using Mac Office 2011 so any code has to work with the Mac version of Excel.

I've tried using Replace.Regex, Split and all other Replace functions I could find. The code below is the best I have come up with in order to do this but it's not adding the comma and the space to the end of the string pattern.

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, x, y

    Set r = Cells.Find("?*, Cat. *", , , 1)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Do
            ' Search for any string with the pattern Cat. 123, Cat. 14, etc
            x = Split(r.Value, " Cat. ")
            If x(UBound(x)) Like "* *" Then
             ' Replace string Cat. 123 with the new string Cat. 123, 
                y = Split(x(UBound(x)))
                x(0) = "Cat. " & y(0) & ", " & x(0)
                x(UBound(x)) = y(1)
            Else
                y = x(UBound(x))
                x(0) = "Cat. " & y & ", " & x(0)
                x(UBound(x)) = ""
            End If
            r.Value = Join(x)
            Set r = Cells.FindNext(r)
        Loop Until r Is Nothing
    End If
  End Sub
```

---

So the output of each cell that contains a pattern like the following examples: "Cat. 123" "Cat. 1" "Cat. 34" "Cat. 4567", would be changed to "Cat. 123, " "Cat. 1, " "Cat. 34, " "Cat. 4567, " NOTE: The original string will always have a period after the word "Cat" and will then be followed by a space and then followed with a single digit all the way up to four digits as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try (this time without vbscript dependent regex):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim lCatLoc As Long
    Dim lNextSpace As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            aData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            aData = .Value
        End If
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
                If Len(aData(i, j)) > 0 Then
                    If aData(i, j) Like "*Cat. [0-9]*" Then
                        lCatLoc = InStr(1, aData(i, j), "Cat. ", vbTextCompare)
                        lNextSpace = InStr(lCatLoc + 5, aData(i, j) & " ", " ", vbTextCompare)
                        sTemp = Mid(aData(i, j), lCatLoc, lNextSpace - lCatLoc)
                        If Right(sTemp, 1) <> "," Then aData(i, j) = Replace(aData(i, j), sTemp, sTemp & ", ")
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        .Value = aData
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works great but only if the text is at the beginning of the cell but not anywhere else.  For example "Cat. 123 is in the house" works but "The big Cat. 123 is not in the house" doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonKeithMcCoy I am unable to replicate that behavior.  It works as expected for me with both example text strings.  I am not on a mac, but the code should run identically on both windows and mac.

Comment: I can't get it to work when "Cat. 123" is anywhere but the beginning